# how to set the initialState with useReducer React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

hi thank you for reading this. I am working a github finder react app that uses useReducer and i am try to set the initialstate when onload to load some users instead of an empty array. if i hard code the api data into the array, it will display as i wanted, but i want to make a GET to the api and pass the data into the array. I am very new to react, thank you all for the help

```
const GithubState = (props) => {
  const initialState = {
    users: [],
    user: {},
    repos: [],
    loading: false,
  };

  //dispatcher
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(GithubReducer, initialState);

  //search Github users
  const searchUsers = async (text) => {
    setLoading();

    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${text}&client_id=${githubClientId}&client_secret=${githubClientaSecret}`
    );

    //dispatch to reducer object
    dispatch({
      type: SEARCH_USERS,
      payload: res.data.items,
    });
  };

//Reducer
import {
  SEARCH_USERS,
  SET_LOADING,
  CLEAR_USERS,
  GET_USER,
  GET_REPOS,
} from "../types";

//action contains type and payload
// export default (state, action) => {
const Reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SEARCH_USERS:
            return {
                ...state,
                users: action.payload,
                loading: false
            }
        case GET_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.payload,
                loading: false
            }
        case GET_REPOS:
            return {
                ...state,
                repos: action.payload,
                loading: false
            }
        case SET_LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        case CLEAR_USERS:
            return {
                ...state,
                users: [],
                loading: false
            }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default Reducer;
```

Comment: Reducer is a function it is not a react component, so it should be `reducer` and `githubReducer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call the `searchUsers()` function in `useEffect()` to get some users and set the state.

if you want to get initial users with some other logic you should probably write a different function and then call it when setting up the component.

```js
const getInitialUsers = async () => {
    setLoading();
    let text = "blabla"; // or whatever your initial user query should look like modify the url below accordingly
    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${text}&client_id=${githubClientId}&client_secret=${githubClientaSecret}`
    );

    //dispatch to reducer object
    dispatch({
      type: SEARCH_USERS,
      payload: res.data.items,
    });
  };

useEffect(()=>{
  getInitialUsers();
},[]);
```

Comment: awesome, it works thank you very much. you're an awesome react guru

Answer (score 0):

The reasonable and suggest place to get your first async data is componentDidMount which in hook world it is translated to use Effect with an empty array as its dependencies

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(githubReducer, initialState);

useEffect(() => {
  searchUsers('initalTextSearchFromPropsOrAnyWhere')
}, [])
```

for more enhancement, you can call `.then`  to show snack bar and `.catch` on to retry in case it fails for some reason and `.finally` to set loading to false in both cases.